# Binary Representation of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: binary

When I recently searched Pascal's triangle on Wolfram Mathworld, the following image appeared.
[image]

Wolfram Mathworld states that this is the binary representation of Pascal's triangle. I am not very familiar with binary representation, and I am not sure how it is generated.

Could any of you provide some explanation or resources to help me understand this beautiful binary representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this representation, each "hump" represents one row of Pascal's triangle, and the columns in each hump are binary representations of the numbers in the corresponding row of the triangle, left-to-right, least significant bit at bottom.

For example, the row $1,4,6,4,1$ corresponds to

```
 111
  1
1   1
```

and the row $1,6,15,20,15,6,1$ to

```
   1
  1 1
 11111
 11 11
1 1 1 1
```